# How to refactor large class that uses "Strategies"?

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, strategy-pattern

### Problem

I have a large class (about 1500 LOC) and it uses different "strategies" to transform data from one object to another.
I have here a representation of that class:

```
public class FooService implements FooProcessing {
    FooRequestTransformer fooRequestTransformer;
    AnotherService anotherService;
    InstanceVar1 iVar1;
    InstanceVar2 iVar2;    
...
```

There is an interface (external to the class) that this class uses:

```
interface TransformerStrategy {
    public FooRequest transform(FooResponse response);
}
```

Which is passed into this method (inside the FooService class):

```
private FooResponse getResponse(FooResponse fooResponse, TransformerStrategy transformerStrategy) {
    FooRequest fooRequest = transformerStrategy.transform();
    fooResponse = anotherService.bar(fooRequest); 
    return fooResponse;
}
```

The entry point is here which uses the `getResponse()` method and creates a `TransformerStrategy` anonymously:

```
public List<Foo> getFooForSomeFlow1(Param1 param1, Param2 param2, ...){
    FooResponse fooResponse = anotherService.baz(fooRequest);

    TransformerStrategy myTransformerStrategy = new TransformerStrategy() {
        public FooRequest transform(FooResponse fooResponse) {
            fooRequestTransformer.transform(param1, param2, iVar1, iVar2) 
        }
    }

    FooResponse fooResponse = getResponse(fooResponse, myTransformerStrategy);
    ...//other code
}
```

Now the problem is: there are *several* methods like `getFooForSomeFlow1()` (inside `FooService`) that all have their own anonymous implementation of `TransformerStrategy` and subsequently call `getResponse()`.  As you can imagine, this is very messy, as well as confusing when you debug (i.e. you are stepping into `getResponse()` and then all of a sudden you are back in `getFooForSomeFlow1()`)

### Possible solution

One possible solution (that comes to mind) is to organize these different strategies into a "Provider" class that will group them together somehow.  Strangely enough, this class *already includes* this type of Provider class:

```
protected class StrategyProvider {
    public ABCTransformerStrategy newABCTransformerStrategy(FooRequestTransformer transformer, Param1 param1, Param2 param2) {
        return new ABCTransformerStrategy(transformer, param1, param2);
    }
}

protected class ABCTransformerStategy implements TransformerStrategy {
    protected FooRequestTransformer transformer;
    protected Param1 param1; 
    protected Param2 param2;

    //...constructor here

    //...overridden transform method as above
}
```

In one of the comments it says, "Converted anonymous class to inner class for testing purposes".  However, they only converted *one* of them, and left the rest of them.  So it's like they started the process of refactoring and stopped in the middle.

So, I was thinking I could finish the process of refactoring and move all the anonymous classes to inner classes, and then finally move out these classes and `StrategyProvider` into external classes.
The problem is that "converting anonymous to inner" adds more boilerplate (see `ABCTransformerStrategy` above; I have to pass in all the data to the constructor) and I'm not really sure how much I'm gaining by doing this refactoring process.

I have two questions:

1. Should I continue with this approach?
2. Or is there another design pattern that I can apply that would be more appropriate and really simplify this code?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, deleted when I realized.

Comment: np, I deleted my comment and clarified the problem a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried irreputable's approach and tried "Inline Method" on the `getResponse()` method, but it was inlining some duplicate code (which is why we extracted that duplicate code into `getResponse()` in the first place).  I should have clarified that in my question that there is more code in `getResponse()` than what I showed.
As for making a Factory, I couldn't justify introducing more boilerplate and LOC into the class, especially since I have to pass a lot of data into the Factory Method and/or Inner Class.

What we did instead was, we wrapped the the anonymous inner classes with a method like so:

```
private TransformerStrategy createTransformerStrategyWithABCValues(Param1 param1, Param2 param2, IVar ivar, IVar1 ivar2) {
    return new TransformerStrategy() {
        public FooRequest transform(FooResponse response) {
            return FooRequestTransformer.transform(
                    param1,
                    param2,
                    iVar1,
                    iVar2);
        }
    };
}
```

Now the calling method looks like this:

```
public List<Foo> getFooForSomeFlow1(Param1 param1, Param2 param2, ...){
    FooResponse fooResponse = anotherService.baz(fooRequest);
    TransformerStrategy myTransformerStrategy = createTransformerStrategyWithABCValues(param2, param2, iVar1, iVar2);
    FooResponse fooResponse = getResponse(fooResponse, myTransformerStrategy);
    ...//other code
}
```

In the process of doing this, we found that the 5 strategies had some duplication, so we were able to get that down to 3 strategies.  We got rid of the StrategyProvider class as well as the inner class that was provided.

With this approach it's now somewhat easier to debug/maintain, and we were able to cut quite a bit of duplication out of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your provider class is actually a [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which is exactly what I was going to suggest.

By moving the logic out of the `getFooForSomeFlow1` and similar methods, you've created very loosely coupled code, which is always desirable.

Simply out of personal preference, I would have one method, used to return instances, that takes an `int` value as the Discriminator. These int's could be static final variables inside the provider class, like:

```
public static final int ABCTransformerStrategy = 1;
```

Additionally, by making the Factory class Abstract, you will remove the need to instantiate the class every time you need to use it, making for much cleaner code.

**Edit**

As suggested, using `Enum` is a much more desirable, and semantically correct way of translating values to the concrete classes they represent.

Comment: A preferred alternative to using an `int` is using an `Enum` to identify which concrete instance needs to be created.

Comment: Agreed. I will factor into my answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code sample you provided, it is superficially complicated. Why not simply

```
public List<Foo> getFooForSomeFlow1(Param1 param1, Param2 param2, ...)
{
    FooResponse fooResponse = anotherService.baz(fooRequest);

    FooRequest  fooRequest = fooRequestTransformer
                                 .transform(param1, param2, iVar1, iVar2); 

    FooResponse fooResponse2 = anotherService.bar(fooRequest);
    ...//other code
}
```

Unless there's something else going on that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a bunch of related objects, you can always use the `Abstract Factory`. It is not a simple design pattern, but is the most suitable here for you.

Take a look at this: [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Convert each method into its own class ([method object pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/implementation-patterns/method-object) i.e., method-as-object), which is similar to where the original refactor was going. If you need to centralize access to all of these methods-as-objects implement an [abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). From your description it sounds like you are transforming from one type to another, so make the abstract factory accept two `Class` parameters and return to the caller the appropriate method-as-object instance for the combination of classes.